# How to convert year into %Y%m%d %H:%M:%S?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a year list (format date) and I would to transform this year into a `%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S` format and the month must be 01 and day must be 01 as in the example below :

`1800` transformed in `1800/01/01 00:00:00`

Anybody as a solution ?

Comment: Take a look at `?paste0` and `?as.POSIXct`.

Answer (score 3):

Try zoo library:

```
library(zoo)
> (date <- as.POSIXct(as.yearmon(2010)))
[1] "2010-01-01 GMT"
> format(date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2010/01/01 00:00:00"
```

EDIT: @user3370470 Please explain yourself. The below confirm what I've been saying so far.

```
> format(as.POSIXct(as.yearmon(1800)), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "1800/01/01 00:00:00"
> format(as.yearmon(1800), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "1800/01/01 00:00:00"
```

The result of `as.POSIXct(as.yearmon(1800)` is a datetime object, class `POSIXct`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this not function well because I have  %H:%M:%S not in a 00:00:00 format. The Gavin Kelly's answer is very good.

Comment: @user3370470 I don't understand the above result is exactly as you asked... please clarify

Comment: @user3370470 Have you figured why `%H:%M:%S not in a 00:00:00 format` ? I still don't see the different between the above method and your requirements...

Comment: This answer does correctly transform 1800 to 1800/01/01 00:00:00 which appears to be the question you asked.  If that is not what you intended please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and improve the question accordingly.

Comment: In fact I have a date type respond like : 1800/01/01 00:09:21 or 1800/01/01 01:00:00 for all my data. But I want to deduct this date list from an other date list and it's important for me to have strictly a date format : 1800/01/01 00:00:00. May be a problem with the type of my date ? I don't know ... For me, the Gavin Kelly's command return all the date format 1800/01/01 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a `date` format - there's a `Date` class, do you mean that.  If the only info you have is the year, then why not `sprintf("%s/01/01 00:00:00", charYear)` where charYear is a vector of string representations of the year.

Comment: Nice, and you can easily wrap the above like : `as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s/01/01 00:00:00", 2010))` and get an actual datetime class, cause it is in the default format.